# How and when to rewrite jQuery callbacks into promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I consider rewriting existing callback-based code into code using promises. However I'm unsure if this makes sense and how to start. The following code-snippet is a mostly self-contained example from that code:

```
function addTooltip($element, serverEndpoint, data) {
'use strict';

const DELAY = 300;
const TOOLTIP_PARENT_CLASS = 'hasTooltip';
let timeOutReference;
$element.hover(function hoverStart() {
    if ($element.hasClass(TOOLTIP_PARENT_CLASS)) {
        return;
    }
    timeOutReference = setTimeout(function getToolTip() {
        const $span = jQuery('<span class="serverToolTip">');
        $span.html(jQuery('<span class="waiting">'));
        $element.append($span);
        $element.addClass(TOOLTIP_PARENT_CLASS);
        jQuery.get(serverEndpoint, data).done(function injectTooltip(response) {
            $span.html(response.data);
        }).fail(handleFailedAjax);
    }, DELAY);
}, function hoverEnd() {
    clearTimeout(timeOutReference);
});
};
```

Intended functionality: When the user hovers over `$element` for 300ms the tooltip-content is requested from the server and appended to `$element`.

Does it make sense to rewrite that code with promises and how would I do it?

<sup>(jQuery is provided by the framework (dokuwiki), so we might as well use it.)</sup>

### Prior research:

- https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html
- other SO questions about this topic which left me unsure about whether this is a sensible idea and how to do it

Comment: It's only worth doing if you've got callbacks in your callbacks (or you may want this functionality in the future). If it's just a simple, `when done, do X` and nothing else depends on when it's done (as appears to be the case with the snippet you posted), then it really doesn't matter and isn't worth a re-write.

Comment: `.done` and `.fail` are promises really since `jQuery.get` returns a promise

Comment: Would make more sense to turn this into a jQuery plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'd need to wrap `setTimeout` into a promise. Simply create a function that accepts a timeout and returns a promise that resolves after that timeout.

Next, since `jQuery.get` already returns a promise, you just need to put it inside the promise resolve handler and return its promise. That way the next chained `then` listens to that promise instead of the timer's.

It would look something like:

```
function timer(n){
  return Promise(function(resolve){
    setTimeout(resolve, n);
  });
}

timer(DELAY).then(function(){
  return jQuery.get(...)
}).then(function(response){
  // jQuery.get promise resolved
}).catch(function(error){
  // something failed somewhere
});
```

As for your question

> Does it make sense to rewrite that code with promises and how would I do it?

That depends on you. I find promise-based code more readable but takes time to write properly especially if if you intend to write pure callbacks and deal with multiple async operations. I usually write my code callbacks-first if the API is simpler to write that way and refactor later for readability.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment above. Below is an example of how promises can make dependent-callback code (arguably) more readable (Basically, it destroys the nesting of callbacks-in-callbacks):

Again, in the case of the code snippet you posted, I hardly see how it's worth it (unless your doing it as an exercise).

**With Callbacks**

```
function someAsyncMethod(callback) {
   $.get({...})
   .then(callback);
}

function anotherAsyncMethod(callback) {
   $.get({...})
   .then(callback);
}

someAsyncMethod(function() {
   anotherAsyncMethod(function yourFunction() {
      //do something
   });
});
```

**With Promises:**

```
function someAsyncMethod() {
  return $.get({...});
}

function anotherAsycnMethod() {
  return $.get({...});
}

someAsyncMethod()
 .then(anotherAsyncMethod)
 .then(function yourFunction() {
    //do something
  })
```